# Determine file format of the font in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I have a desktop WPF application which allows user to customize fonts.

After investigating rendering performance, I found that OpenType fonts render noticeably faster, than TrueType fonts.I would like to filter out TrueType fonts from settings dialog, so user can only select OpenType fonts.
But I can't find how to determine the format of font in WPF.

I looked in **Fonts.SystemFontFamilies** and **Fonts.SystemTypefaces** and can't find any relevant properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Windows comes with any OpenType fonts, so unless you install them yourself, `Fonts.SystemFontFamilies` won't contain any.

That said, you could try filtering the list by retrieving the font's file name:

```
GlyphTypeface glyph;
var fonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.Where(f => f.GetTypefaces().Any(t => 
     t.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph) &&
     glyph.FontUri.ToString().EndsWith("otf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Another way is to use the private `FontTechnology` proeprty:

```
GlyphTypeface glyph;
var FontTechnologyProperty = typeof(GlyphTypeface).GetProperty("FontTechnology", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var OpenType = Enum.Parse(FontTechnologyProperty.PropertyType, "PostscriptOpenType");
var fonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.Where(f => f.GetTypefaces().Any(t => 
     t.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyph) &&
     Object.Equals(FontTechnologyProperty.GetValue(glyph), OpenType)));
```

Comment: Hm. I can see that Arial is OpenType. Segoe UI too. It seems there are lots of OpenType fonts in my Windows 7SP1 installation.

Comment: PS While mentioned fonts have .ttf extension. System font viewer tell they have OpenType format...

Comment: Thanks for you help. Your could should work, but it find zero items. I found this internal property too, and there are really no fonts marked with PostscriptOpenType on my system. I will look for other solution.